# Simple SQL commands for C#

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am not too experienced with SQL but am fairly strong in C#. I am coding an app that requires a local database, and I choose to use a simple SQL Database. I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express, and have the SQL package that came with the download. The way I created the database was:

- Right-Click on the project in solution explorer>Add>New Item...
- Local Database, named Database1
- I then create a table called Table1
- Data>Add New Data Source --- Database>Dataset>[It creates a new connection/dataset called                                          Database1DataSet1]

Can give me a link/explination with good instructions of how to do simple things such as set variables to entries, create new entries, delete entries etc. ?

Thank you

Comment: "Fairly strong in C#" and using "Database1DataSet1"...

Comment: @Blindy: I suppose it's entirely possible that Squeakers has worked for years in real time systems development using C# without needing to perform any database interaction... but I agree, that's highly unlikely. ;)

Answer (score 5):

This is not a question easily answered in a forum such as this. Working effectively with databases requires more than a simple tutorial. I suggest that you pick up a good SQL Server / .NET book.

The reason I claim this is that whilst a tutorial might show you how to get things done, knowing **why** things are done the way they are simply requires more knowledge than what can be expressed in a tutorial format. And knowing the theory is mandatory to avoid databases turn into a nightmare.

I believe this book would be nice entry point

[Beginning C# 2008 Databases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599004)

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth considering NHibernate to perform your object mapping. There are some pretty easy to follow tutorials on the net for things like auto configured databases etc.

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateForNET

Comment: I would think that the OP probably needs to understand a bit more about databases and how they work before going down the ORM path.  Introducing an ORM without any fundamental understanding would just confuse them.

Comment: I agree. Start with the basics, or things gets messy before you can say nhibernate

Comment: fair comment, just from a personal perspective some of the auto configure fluent NHibernate stuff can effectively hide the DB implementation from the developer. If you are a pure c# guy and "just want your model persisted" it can be simpler and quicker. You dont have to understand how ALL of it works to get a result. Therefore it can be a valid option